# Web3 js events not listening after 5 mins of idle time

Tags: web3js, events, precompiled-contracts

My contract is deployed on ropsten infura test-network and that contract has events which gets fired when there is some transaction.

contract file

```
function functionName(address from, address destination, uint256 amount) stoppable public {
        myEvent(from, destination, amount);
}
```

I am trying to listen this event in my node js code in below manner

```
let web3 = new Web3()
web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws'));

Contract.events.myEvent(function (err, res) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Event Log :', res);
      }
})
```

After restarting node server and doing instant transactions which calls method "functionName" from contract which emits event, node js is properly listening for the events and I am getting expected output.

But if I wait 5 min or more idle without making any transactions or any activity and if I make transaction after that interval the method from contract "functionName" is getting called but node js is not able to listen for that event.

Can any one please let me know if you face such issues ever.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different rpc endpoint . Some examples are Alchemy , getblocks